# Тернарный оператор в цикле PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Интересует тернарный оператор в php. Написал такую вот функцию:

```
function links()
{
    if ($qname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook"))
    {
        $qnum = mysql_num_rows($qname);

        for ($i = 1; $i < ($qnum < 10 ? 1 : $qnum / 10) ; $i++)
        {
             echo "<div class='links'>"."<a href='/testphp/guestbook/guestbook.php?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a>"."</div>";
        }
     echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

php ругается "Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource..."
так нельзя?

Comment: Начиная с того, что ругается оно на mysql_fetch_rows, коего я тут не наблюдаю и который к тернарному относится чуть менее, чем никак... =D

Comment: да нет же, именно на него и ругается. 
вообще, синтаксически это верно?
    for ($i = 1; $i < ($qnum < 10 ? 1 : $qnum / 10) ; $i++)

Comment: В упор не вижу там Mysql... Синтаксически-то верно, но не понимаю, что вы сей строкой хотели добиться=3

Comment: функция создает ссылки вида 1, 2, 3 ... на каждой странице по 10 записей. т.е. если записей стало 11, создается ссылка 2. для того, чтобы узнать, надо ли создавать ссылку, я узнаю, сколько строк в базе данных есть. если их меньше 10, то ничего создавать не надо и цикл. если больше, то делим количество записей на 10 и создаем ссылку 2. 
как-то так. )
коряво?

Comment: Здесь можно обойтись простеньким математическим выражением, который даст тот же результат=)

Comment: поделитесь?

Comment:     $num_pages = ceil(mysql_num_rows($qname)/10); И тогда можно без $qnum обойтись. Да и вообще, для получения количества записей в таблице пользуйтесь select count(*) from `table`.

Comment: да, вы были правы, ругался он совсем не на тернарный. все работает. и за select count(*) спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я давно на PHP не писал, но, насколько помню - правильно. И проблема где-то в другом месте.

Заодно позволю себе посмотреть на Ваш код с другой стороны ;) Предположим, у Вас в гостевой записей пара миллионов - спасибо спамботу. Может, стоит тогда на уровне SQL-запроса выбрать количество "не более чем"? Например вот такой всевдо-SQL-код:

```sql
SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE (какое-то условие)
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET 10*(page-1)
```

где `page` - номер текущей страницы.

Для выяснения же общего количества записей лучше использовать отдельный запрос, например:
`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM guestbook`

Еще маленький совет: используйте наиболее свежие библиотеки доступа к MySQL, а еще лучше - используйте ORM.